# Vue production build is failing, Where to look for error?

Tags: vue.js, npm-run

I am building a web app in Vue 2.6.11.  I can run it on my local machine with npm run serve, but when I try to build it for production with npm run build I get the following error messages:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'cliui'
```

This is the build log file.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~prebuild: jumbletrail@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: jumbletrail@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\development\jumbletrail\jumbletrail\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\bin;d:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\nodejs\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin;C:\Users\aaron\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\;C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: CWD: D:\development\jumbletrail\jumbletrail
10 silly lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle jumbletrail@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: jumbletrail@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid jumbletrail@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\development\jumbletrail\jumbletrail
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error jumbletrail@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the jumbletrail@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Where should I be looking for the build error.  I have tried npm install to refresh the npm packages with no success?
The project is using vuex and azure serverless functions for API calls, with an .env.local and .env.production files pointing at the relevant API endpoints for dev and prod.  The endpoints are working when I swap the production end point into the local file

Comment: have you installed `npm i cliui` manually and tried to rebuild?

Answer (score 2):

@HelloWorld
You are a genious!
I ran

```
 npm install cliui --save production
```

and it has worked